# Pass props to material-ui styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a function that maps trough an array of objects and finally renders that data out as a chart. My problem is, I want to pass the item from the map function to material-ui make styles so I can style the output based on items proprietes.

Eg of what I would like to do:

```
 <div className={classes.chartcontainer}>
        {array.map(entry=>(
    <Grid className={classes.chartBar} entry={entry} />
    ))}
    </div>
```

and then in make styles I would like to get the entry prop and style the component based on entry's proprietes

eg:

```
chartBar:{
height:entry.ammount > 100 ? "50px" : "30px"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use static props in the material-ui classes, when you use `useStyles(props)` for example.

In your loop, my advice is to just create two classes:

```js
// The looop:
<div className={classes.chartcontainer}>
  {array.map(entry=>(
    <Grid 
       className={entry.amount > 50 ? classes.largeChartBar :classes.smallChartBar} 
       entry={entry} />
    ))}
</div>

// styles:
largeChartBar:{
  height: 50
},

smallChartBar:{
  height: 30
}
```

Alternatively, use dynamic styles:

```js
<div className={classes.chartcontainer}>
  {array.map(entry=>(
    <Grid entry={entry} styles={{height: entry.amount}}/>
    ))
  }
</div>
```